# Use of ternary operator in formal writing

Tags: notation, mathematical-writing

I would like to write
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}1&\mbox{if }x = 1\\ 0&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
However, this eats up a lot of vertical space for a very simple statement. Is there agreed upon or common notation to inline this into a single normal-height line in technical writing? As a computer scientist I am tempted to write
$$
f(x) = (x=1\,?\,1 : 0),
$$
which is the notation of the common programming notation for the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). If you were reviewing a paper that did this (saying that it used the ternary operator notation of C++) would you declare it an abomination? Is there an alternative that you would consider?

Comment: I'd use the first version. The ternary operator is not common notation in math papers and I at least would be confused by it. I suppose it might depend on the field though.

Comment: $f(x) = \delta_{x,1}$ or $f(x) = 1_{\{1\}}(x)$

Comment: I'd use $f(x) = \delta_{x=1}$, probably.

Comment: I would write a sentence: "Define $f(x)=1$ if $x=1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise."

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to use the ternary operator provided it's clearly defined (and provided it's used often enough to make the gain of space worth while). A compromise might be to write $f(x) = (\mathtt{if~}x=1\mathtt{~then~}1\mathtt{~else~}0)$.

Comment: I use the ternary operator quite often in notes that I write for myself, and I would be happy if it were more widely accepted in the mathematical literature.  I suggest that you make a LaTeX macro for it, so you can change back to more standard notation fairly easily if the referee complains.

Comment: Note:  in many programming languages $"=="$ is equality operator and $"="$ is assignment operator, so: $f(x) = (x==1\,?\,1 : 0)$

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator doesn't seem to be used in mathematical papers, with the vertical brace notation being the most popular option. If there is a strong reason for not using the vertical brace (such as it being embedded in a more complicated expression), I would suggest using the **Iverson bracket**:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket

in which case you would write $f(x) = [x = 1]$. Even then, the Iverson bracket might not necessarily be known to your reader, in which case you could use the vertical brace the *first* time you introduce the Iverson bracket:

$$ f(x) = [x = 1] := \begin{cases}1&\mbox{if }x = 1\\ 0&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases} $$

Then, any subsequent time you use the Iverson bracket, its meaning should be understood without the need for a clarifying brace:

$$ \delta_{ij} = [i = j] $$

Comment: I also immediately thought of the Iverson bracket, and frequently find occasion to use it.  However, perhaps just out of mathematical conservatism, I think that @TomGoodwillie's comment http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239098/use-of-ternary-operator-in-formal-writing#comment591530_239098 is better; if space is at such a premium, then prefer a written explanation to the use of what will for many readers be an *ad hoc* symbolism.  (Of course, the same objection could have been urged against Recorde's use of '=' in place of 'equals', and I think it's good that it wasn't.  :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Even the Iverson bracket is used only in certain parts of mathematics.  If the "cases" notation is absolutely ruled out (perhaps because it is to be used a few hundred times), then my inclination is to follow Steve Hartsman and use the indicator function (a.k.a. characteristic function)
$$
f = \mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}
\\
f = \chi_{\{1\}}
$$
or similar.

Comment: I know that you explicitly don't advocate them, but I think that both of those have problems.  As a representation theorist, I prefer to reserve $\chi$ for characters, rather than characteristic functions.  I don't have any particularly principled objection to $\mathbb 1$ for characteristic functions; I just find it ugly.  A modification of the Iverson bracket mentioned by [@AdamP.Goucher](http://mathoverflow.net/a/239105/2383), and which I have heard attributed to Kottwitz, uses brackets:  $[\{1\}]$.  Of course, a big problem with all of these is that they give no idea what the domain is!